# Help me add outputs from a two 3 to 8 decoders

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, logic-analyzer

I have built two 3 to 8 decoders, so that I can get an octal output 0-7 from each.
Now, I need to be able to add these outputs to determine wether a number is greater than 7 or not.

I have tried to come up with several solutions but I am just stuck. Can someone give me some directions please. Also I can only use the basic logic gates (OR, AND, NOT). I am using logisim to test.

Comment: Why not just add the two binary numbers and use a magnitude comparator?

Answer (score 0):

Easier to start with the binary and not decode it first.

You will note that greater then 7 is a special case, as it implies that the carry out on a three bit adder will be 1 if and only if the sum of the two three bit inputs is larger then 7.

The carry out from an adder stage is 1 if at least two of the three inputs (Cin, A,B) are 1, and we do not really care about the sum term, so we can write, Cout  = AB + C(A+B), which I make to be two 'or' and two 'and' gates per bit (Except the LSB where C is known to be 0 and this degenerates to a single and gate).

Where A,B are the two input bits and C is the carry in (0 for the first stage). 
Let F(A,B,C) be the logic element described above, then Out = F(a[2],b[2],F(a[1],b[1],F(a[0],b[0],0))). Out will be one only if the sum exceeds 7.

5 And terms, 4 Or terms, purely combinatorial logic, but note that the output will be prone to glitches on input transitions as there are race paths.